# software recommandation for green screen photo editing

Tags: software-rec

I'm looking for something that would allow me to replace the specific green parts of a still picture (green-screen photo) with another image, all that called from a shell script.

Basically, a command line [Chroma key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) for picture.

I guess Photoshop could do it (with it's weird scripting language), but this project can't afford such an investment (and I'd like to keep it as much Open Source as possible).

I'm pretty sure the GIMP could also handle that, but I know nothing about its scripting capabilities and I suppose there are better software options for such a specific task...

The typical platform would be debian-based, running on an ARM64 (or x64 if no other option).

Any suggestion would be welcome!

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Gimp is scriptable via python. There's also some macro recording tools, and tools for batch application of operations to images.

GraphicsMagick's gm can probably also do something like that, though I haven't tried. I'd directly go for openCV in the shape of the cv2 python3 library. In your simple case, the PIL / pillow library would probably do as well.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcusMüller !


Using Gimp, though it is scriptable and have macros, might be a bit too complicated and load-heavy for the task.

I like the idea of a python script, so a library might very well be the best option! I had no idea python had such libs!
Now I have a lot to read and much to try! Thanks again!